# PowerShell split value on separate lines

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a script below. I want to run and gets report of all Office 365 mailboxes. But one attribute **EmailAddresses** has more than value, which I want to cleanup by removing the **SMTP** at the beginning, this part is fine, it's the split at the end I am stuck with, I want to split this out onto how ever many lines as needed based on how many email addresses their are. I do **count**, but building the custom array at the bottom doesn't work.

```
Get-Mailbox `
           | ForEach{
           $DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
           $PrimarySmtpAddress = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
           $alias = $_.alias
           $UserPrincipalName = $_.UserPrincipalName
           $EmailAddresses = $_.EmailAddresses
           $OtherProxyAddress = $_.EmailAddresses -cmatch "smtp:" -replace "smtp:",""
           $StepProxyAddress = ($OtherProxyAddress).count
           $number = 0
           $UserPrincipalName | Select-Object `
           @{n="DisplayName";e={$DisplayName}},`
           @{n="alias";e={$alias}},`
           @{n="UserPrincipalName";e={$UserPrincipalName}},`
           @{n="PrimarySmtpAddress";e={$PrimarySmtpAddress}},`
           @{Name="PrimaryProxyAddresses"; Expression={$EmailAddresses -cmatch "SMTP:" -replace "SMTP:",""}},`
           do {@{Name="OtherProxyAddress" + $number++; Expression={($OtherProxyAddress)[$number]}}} until($number -eq $StepProxyAddress)
           }
```

Here is the original value for **$OtherProxyAddress**:

```
fred.smith@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
fred.smith@company.com
```

I want the output (for this attribute in particular) to be:

```
OtherProxyAddress1  fred.smith@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
OtherProxyAddress2  fred.smith@company.com
```

Comment: An example of original value and desired result might help.

Comment: Here is the origional value for `$OtherProxyAddress`:

fred.smith@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
fred.smith@company.com

     I want the output (for this attribute in particular) to be:

`OtherProxyAddress1 fred.smith@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
OtherProxyAddress2 fred.smith@company.com`

Comment: @MarcKean That is nice but can you add that to your question and show us what you want the output to look like in the question. I ask because seeing what you want is the only way we can be sure. I can guess but if I am wrong it would be a waste of my time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want something like this (assuming that the `EmailAddresses` property contains an array of e-mail addresses of the form `smtp:localpart@example.com`):

```psh
Get-Mailbox | % {
  $o = New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
         'DisplayName'         = $_.DisplayName
         'alias'               = $_.alias
         'UserPrincipalName'   = $_.UserPrincipalName
         'PrimarySmtpAddress'  = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
         'PrimaryProxyAddress' = ($_.EmailAddresses | select -First 1) -replace '^smtp:'
       }

  $i = 1
  $_.EmailAddresses | select -Skip 1 | % {
    $o | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "OtherProxyAddress$i" `
      -Value ($_ -replace '^smtp:')
    $i++
  }

  $o
}
```

First you build a custom object with the "simple" properties, then you add each e-mail address as a separate property to that object by using [`Add-Member`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849879.aspx) in a nested loop.

Comment: Would this not cause an issue if the object has more additional addresses beyond the first created? I was going to do this but was going to calculate the maximum number of addresses so that each object would have the same amount

Comment: @Matt My understanding of the question was that he wants one property per address, regardless of how many addresses there are. He may want to skip the first address, though, since that's already the `PrimaryProxyAddress`. Updated.

Comment: I changed the lines (line 8 and 12) `'PrimaryProxyAddress' = $_.EmailAddresses -cmatch "SMTP:" -replace '^smtp:'` and `$_.EmailAddresses -cmatch "smtp:" | % {` using cmatch is more acurate, as the capitals SMTP address is the primary proxy address. However in doing this, I now have **{}** either side of the email address in the results. How can I remove the {} from the results?

Comment: Actually, think I worked it out, change the line to be `'PrimaryProxyAddress' = ($_.EmailAddresses) -cmatch "SMTP:" -replace '^smtp:' -join ' ' ` the join function did the trick